# How to configure the path of files inside a folder in Struts config file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts, struts-tags

I created a folder named `customer` and I placed the following JSP files inside it
`edit.jsp`, `editsuccess.jsp`.

My struts config is

```
<action input="/customer/edit.jsp" name="Edit" path="/edit" scope="request"  type="Controller.Editctr">
   <forward name="success" path="/customer/editsuccess.jsp"/>
</action>
```

In this `edit.jsp` is input page and `editsuccess.jsp` is the output page for the controller (Servlet) named `Editctr` and a path of the controller is `edit`.
Here I am calling the servlet in the front end through JSP

```
<form action="edit.do" method="post">
```

When I submit the form it shows the following error

> HTTP Status 404 - Invalid path was requested

I tried some possible ways of changing but still I couldn't able to fix it.

Comment: It should be /WEB-INF/customer/editsuccess.jsp in your forward tag. Same applies for input attribute

Comment: @almas shaikh it's not working

Comment: If you are learning Struts then better do it using latest version. The version you use is already dead and only immortals still working on it.

Comment: could somebody help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using html form tag then you should map the action properly.

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextpath}/edit.do" method="post">
```

or use html taglib

```
<%@ taglib prefix="html" uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" %>

<html:form action="/edit" method="post">
```